# Graphs and Grouping with SUMIF?

Tags: excel, graph, grouping, spreadsheet

In one column, I have a day column, eg. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
In another column next to it, I have a number value. (eg. $2000, $5000, $6000)
eg.

```
__DATE__________VALUE____
Monday      |  $5000
Monday      |  $9000
Tuesday     |  $2000
Wednesday   |  $6000
Wednesday   |  $6000
```

These values will ***change periodically***.

I need to insert a graph, that displays the grouped values. 
eg. At current point, the graph shows:

```
Monday       $5000
Monday       $9000
Tuesday      $2000
Wednesday    $6000
Wednesday    $15000
```

I need the graph to instead show the same values, but grouped by DAY:

```
Monday    $14000
Tuesday   $2000
Wednesday $21000
```

As I said, both the day and the value next to it will change when need be, so I would prefer this to be grouped automatically with some sort of forumla.

Is there any way to do this?

I have had a read on the SUMIF function, but can't seem to make it work with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a **Pivot Chart**. This is very easy to create, though will vary depending on your excel version.

[image: Pivot Chart!]

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Except for one thing. It doesn't update when data is changed.

Comment: Actually seems like you're right, I forgot they don't auto update. In any case you can right click on the table or chart and select 'Refresh Data', also there is an option to refresh it automatically every time you open the file. Strangely you can't make it auto update, not sure why. @DanielNitschke

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to be up to date as you add more information, another option would be to put a SUMIF formula in a section of the workbook, like another tab or hidden column/row, and have the graph look off that.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkC4f.png)